# load form using jquery ajax and resubmit that form without page refresh

Tags: ajax, forms, loaded

i want to submit form which loaded via jquery without refreshing the whole page.
but this code first load form without refreshing whole page then the form loaded via jquery refreshes whole page on submission.
how to solve this problem??

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click",".down",function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var name = $("#down").attr("name");
         var vote = $("#down").val();
         var voteString = 'votedown='+ vote;
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: 'vote.php',
             data: voteString,
             cache: false,
             error: function() {
                 $('#btn-vote').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
             },

         beforeSend: function() {
             $('#load').html("<img src='../images/LoaderIcon.gif' />");
         },
         success: function(html) {
             $("#re").html(html);
         }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The on function takes a selector as well, that way you can use it on elements loaded with ajax. You also have to bind it to an element that exists when the page loads.

```
$('body').on('click', 'selector of the element created', function(){
  ...
})
```

Obviously you should not use body probably but a closer parent of the loaded element.

Comment: trying this but not working                       $(".down").on("click",".down",function(e) {...}

Comment: form loaded via jquery refreshing whole page, after refreshing again i click  on submit then it submitting without refreshing page.

Comment: <form method="post">                                            
<input class="votes" id="up" name="voteup" value="voteup" <?php echo $up; ?> type="hidden"/>
<button class="up"<?php echo $up; ?> ></button>
</form>   this is my form. @sebastian W

Comment: You have to do the first selector on a parent of the created element that exists when the page is loaded. So the first selector is "body" for example

Comment: $("body").on("click",".down",function(e) {...}, however it should preferably be on the closest parent

Comment: I see now ur class is wrong too. you should add a class or id to the form and use submit instead of click as well

Comment: now changed class and used submit instead click but not working @Sebastian W

Comment: Weird, it should. Im on mobile now so i cant really test. Wil answer better whn home

Comment: actually using this code for voting system.   problem is when submitting vote for first time on opening that page , it works without refreshing page but again want to change vote, it first reload whole page then again clicking on vote button to change vote but i don't want to reload the page  @Sebastian W

Comment: i will be waiting for your answer @Sebastian W

Comment: $("body").on("click",".up",function(e) {...} ); used this now working.

Comment: thanks for giving valuable time and solution @ Sebastian W